# iOS, Objective C Presenting NavigationController modal and adding cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to present a View Controller modal. So i created a new Navigation Controller and called `initWithRootViewController`
The Problem is that i want to create a cancel Button in the Navigation bar but i just can not do it.
First of all is it even possible to set the button and text up on the navigation bar from outside and not in the Navigation Controller?

And if it is how can I do it because setting a new custom `navigationItem` does not work ?

Comment: what you want to do and what is problem faced here ?

Comment: I can not show a Cancel text on the left side of the navigation bar

Comment: how  to add that cancel button ?

Comment: You're presenting the nav controller modally, or you're presenting a third view controller from the nav controller's root controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem on my own. The problem is that i had to set my cancel button in the root view controller and not from outside on the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add both cancel button and title on the top of the navigationbar.

Embade your view controller in a navigation controller and give storyboadId to navigation controller. Then add the code in which class from when you want to present you desired  VC

```
 UINavigationController *initialNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeNavCtrl_id"];
[self presentViewController:initialNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In your desired class in viewDidLoad() add this code

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                           target:self 
                           action:@selector(cancelButtonAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
self.navigationItem.title = @"Wishlist";
```

for cancel button action use this

```
- (IBAction)cancelBtnAction:(id)sender
{
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```